# CSS How to position rounded lines together

Tags: html, css, css-position, tailwind-css

I'm trying to convert design layout to actuall css and i got stuck. This is what I need to achieve:
[image]

I have created a simple version using tailwind but this what I got so far and now i'm stuck and I don't know how to get rid of that space between rounded borders. See bellow:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/mwn6rb4t/1/

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3">
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b  border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2 border-l border-gray-300"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b rounded-bl-lg border-l border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2 border-l border-gray-300"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b rounded-bl-lg border-l border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
</div>
```

I was trying to lay one div border on top of another but when I'm zooming arround sometimes it renders as two lines :/

Comment: Styled components, no way to test this...bad start.

Comment: I've added a tailwind version

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specifically select for those elements that follow a bottom border element, and then give it a negative margin at the top so that it overlaps with the element above it:

```css
.border-b + .h-1\/2.border-l {
  margin-top: -8px;
  height: calc(50% + 8px);
}
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```css
.border-b + .h-1\/2.border-l {
  margin-top: -8px;
  height: calc(50% + 8px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.17/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid grid-cols-3">
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b  border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2 border-l border-gray-300"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b rounded-bl-lg border-l border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2 border-l border-gray-300"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="h-1/2 border-b rounded-bl-lg border-l border-gray-300"></div>
    <div class="h-1/2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-2 h-12 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using margin such as `m-2`on the boxes

Remove these classes for removing space between the boxes and use `margin` in negative to move the boxes of second column to the top

Comment: Those margins should be there, the problem is space arround rounded line corner in the middle.

Comment: Yeah, i get your point, use margin in negative to fill the space rounded line

Comment: When I do that and I zoom arround in some zooms there is a double line then :-/

Comment: Can you show me that ? so I can understand better

Comment: I've added a picture